# PHP and phpMyAdmin is not working after updating to iMac OS Mojave, Catalina

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, apache2, macos-mojave

`You dont have enough permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server.`

[image]

after updating to mac os `Mojave` when I browse to http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php I get the index.php file as text. so php isn't working

[image]

but when I was running php on terminal php -v is working so there isn't a problem with php.

[image]

I think the problem is apache isn't configured to working with php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to tell apache to use php, so I uncommented following line in `apache httpd conf`

open `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` on any text editor

uncomment following line (remove the pre `#` tag)

`LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so`

save the file and exit

now apache is using php, restart apache to effect the changes

`sudo apachectl restart`